# Number of overlaping windows for an audio signal

Tags: math, set, overlap

I have an audio signal, of length n and I want to divide it into windows of length k, with an overlap r < k. What is the number of windows I will obtain, from my audio signal?

I calculated it to be

```
  n/(k-r) - r
```

but I now see that it is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

If you have m windows of length k with an overlap of r, then the total distance span, n, is given as

```
n = (k-r)m + r
```

Hence the number of windows, m, is

```
m = (n-r)/(k-r)
```