# Number of overlapping windows of a given length

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, windowing

I'm writing a code in Matlab with a simple windowing function in order to apply a simple overlap and add algorithm to my input signal.

So far this is what I have written:

```
[s_a,Fs] = audioread('a.wav');
frame_dur = 0.04; %length of my window in time
frame_stride = 0.01; %shift of every single window in time

frame_len = round(frame_dur * Fs); 
frame_step = round(frame_stride*Fs);

win = hamming(frame_len);
```

The window overlapping is given by shift in time instead of a percentage value of its length (so every 10ms I have a window that ends 40ms later.

How do i calculate the number of windows in my signal?

I found this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264209/number-of-overlaping-windows-for-an-audio-signal) but i do not have the overlap `r`. Can I find my number of windows starting from the data I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that `n` is the number of samples in your audio file:

```
n=numel(s_a);
```

When processing your data frame wise (with each window) you would do the follwoing

```
for frame=1:frame_step:(n-(frame_len-1))

    Tmp=s_a(frame:frame+frame_len-1).*win;
    %do something with tmp

end
```

So you can see that the amount of windows that fits into your data can be calculated in the following way:

```
num_win=numel(1:frame_step:(n-(frame_len-1)));
```

Assuming the worst case that `n` is not a multiple of `frame_len` you can calculate it like:

```
num_win=floor((n-(frame_len))/frame_step)+1;
```

Comment: The number of windows changes based on the step size `frame_step`. Here is a slightly modified way to account for this: `num_win = floor((n-frame_len))/frame_step)+mod(n,frame_step);`

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can consider r as:

> frame_dur - frame_stride

and calculate the number of windows (depending on the length of the signal with respect to the stride) with the formula you posted:

> m = (n-r)/(k-r)